# Basic addition of two numbers

Tags: java, addition, inputmismatchexception

Sorry for asking an easy question, but I'm a total beginner here. So the problem is when I copy the following code into my eclipse, it's working fine. But when I change the type of the variables from int to double it's showing some kind of an error. Please check it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AddNumbers
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      double x, y, z;
      System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      x = in.nextDouble();
      y = in.nextDouble();
      z = x + y;
      System.out.println("Sum of entered integers = "+z);
   }
}
```

btw, the error is as following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at AddNumbers.main(AddNumbers.java:10)
```

here's the video tutorial i just watched (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANuuSFY2BbY) i just tried copying it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum;
        double snum;
        double answer;
        System.out.println("Enter first number:");
        fnum = bucky.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second number:");
        snum = bucky.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum+snum;
        System.out.print(answer);
    }

}
```

and i get the following error:

```
Enter first number:
34.6
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:11)
```

Comment: What did you enter?

Comment: What was your input?

Comment: Thilo, Bandi Kishore, 34.6

Comment: It is working fine!

Comment: Working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3BAMN6) - note you have to enter _two_ numbers because you are calling `.nextDouble()` twice.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Answer]

You see. I  get the right answer.
So you have to show your inout like what they have said.

Also you can modify your code like below to make it more stronger.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class AddNumbers
{
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    double x, y, z;
    System.out.println("Enter two double to calculate their sum ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        try {
            x = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
            y = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
            z = x + y;
            System.out.println("Sum of entered double = " + z);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not a double param, please enter again");
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You probably entered something that CANNOT be interpreted as a double ( letters or special charcters ).

You strictly have to enter ONLY numbers.

Check your input.

Comment: I only entered 34.6. Please, if possible, also check out the following tutorial and inform me if it works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANuuSFY2BbY

Comment: You have probably set a Locale that uses `,` instead of `.`.